# Cracking/Creaking noise when pedalling hard or standing on a pedal

Tags: noise, creak

So my 1 month old bike started making a creaking/cracking noise when I pedal hard or stand on a pedal. For example if I only pedal hard on one side and just let the other side spin its fine but as soon as i paddle with both sides it creaks on every stroke.

Since I'm short on tools I've only tried new pedals, taking of the cranks and put them back on with grease, took the chain of and just stood on one pedal then switched to the other one and the noise still appeared. Took out of seat post and checked every bolt/axle/quick release on the bike except the BB. It seems to be a sealed shimano cartridge so is there a way to "fix" it, do I buy a new one since while I'm already at it or can it be something else?

It´s a Fuji Nevada 1.9 29 2021

---

From what I can tell its threaded, looks similar to this one:
[image]

Comment: BB creaking mostly happens with pressfit type. But as you have already tested everything else maybe a local bike shop could grease and reinstall it, as you are short on tools.

Comment: i might just buy the needed tools and do it myself since my local bike shop seems to never open even after calling and getting an appointment.

Comment: Check the bb threads have grease on them. Occasionally the factory don't bother.

Comment: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-tool-selection-threaded-and-thread-together I suggest this to find the correct type of tool you need.

As BB-types and norms are a total mess.

Comment: luckily 20 internal spline seems to only have one size, i ordered one on amazon rn. Lets hope regreasing does the job

Comment: Its a 30 day old bike?  Its a warranty issue, and the more you mess with it the harder it will be to get it fixed under warranty.   Contact the seller and make it known.  Any normal country would require at least 12 months of warranty, and some require 2 years.

Comment: @Chappax [the idea of stack exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) is that even if you find the correct answer yourself, you still post it as answer, which you can then mark as a solution.

Comment: oh i will do that rn, ty for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you buy it? I'm guessing that your local bike store, unless they were the place where you purchased it, probably has little if any interest in working on the bike, unless you are willing to pay a good amount.

I looked at [the specs on this bike](https://www.fujibikes.com/usa/bikes/mountain/sport/nevada/nevada-29-1-9) and the crank/bottom bracket is not precisely described. Pictures would be helpful, but if the bottom bracket has cups that attach it-- [the manufacturer only seems to sell that kind](http://www.pro-wheel.com/main/?product_cat=bottom-brackets)-- my guess would be, you need to remove the cups, put some anti-seize compound on the threads, and torque them down properly.

I had a creak like this on my bike, which was assembled in Taiwan, and upon disassembly, found the BB cups were barely lubricated with a minuscule amount of some all-purpose grease. I put in a proper amount of anti-seize compound, reassembled to spec, and all was well, no more creak.

Comment: Instead of an unwilling LBS you may always find a cycling commune in your area, especially if you bought the bicycle online.

Comment: I bought it online and took almost a month to deliver. Since i need it daily returning it is out of the way after they told me it could take up to 2 months. I have some grease laying around that i used for the cranks. Can i take that for the bb or is something like the shimano anti seize a must have?

Edit: The BB looks exactly like the one i posted before. Only the Cranks are from Prowheel.

Comment: There are sometimes bicycle repair clinics or community bicycle repair events where a person can get a bike worked on by someone who has both reasonable tools and reasonable experience. Probably would take some searching to find, but particularly in urban areas, you may find that even in the COVID era they convene on weekends, etc., and do work for donations or a small fee.

Comment: Regarding the anti-seize compound, the main purpose is to prevent BB cups from cold-welding to the frame via oxidation on the threads, but if your BB doesn't have cups, you still might find that greasing the threads holding in the BB could help. Also check chainring bolts, crank bolts, anything threaded that helps hold crankset together. Generally if your creak occurs when your pedal is at the same location(s) it is crankset- or BB-related. Spokes can rub, but even with wind noise most can identify whether a creak is from the crank or the spokes somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

There can be a number of creak sources. Let me share my example.

I bought a bike with 28-spoke wheels. (Normally, I would not purchase a bike with anything less than 36 spokes per wheel, but unfortunately it has become hard to find bicycles with reasonable spoke count.)

Needless to say, the wheels lost spoke tension after riding a while. The front wheel lost all of its tension on all spokes, and the rear wheel only partially lost tension.

My solution for this was two-fold:

- I made a plan to build myself replacement 36-spoke wheels so that I can have wheels that won't fail
- I asked the bike shop where I purchased the bike from to fix the existing wheels

The "solution" of the bike shop was to put thread glue into every spoke nipple, and to slightly tighten the spokes. After I got the bike back, I rode it for 700 km or so with the "fixed" wheels before building my own wheelset. Upon carefully inspecting the "fixed" wheels, spoke tension on the average was low, wildly fluctuating (so not equivalent on every spoke) and it appeared what kept the spoke nipples from unscrewing was the thread glue.

The spokes on the "fixed" wheelset didn't unscrew anymore due to the thread glue, but a different problem developed on the rear wheel. When riding hard uphill, there was a mysterious creak. I originally assumed the creak would come from a bent rear wheel axle, but now I assume the creak actually came from the spokes, some of which still had inadequate tension.

My replacement rear wheel that I myself built with DT Swiss TK 540 rim, DT Swiss Alpine III spokes, DT Swiss Pro Head brass nipples, and Shimano FH-R7070 hub, did not suffer from the problem at all. Obviously I did not use any thread glue, put enough tension on all spokes, ensured the spoke tensions were equal, stress relieved the wheel carefully in addition to ensuring the wheel is true.

Of course it's theoretically possible that the original rear wheel having a cheap non-Shimano "Formula" hub could have something broken, but I believe it is a plausible theory that the rear wheel spokes are creaking when riding uphill.